# How can i update the counter state each click?

Tags: reactjs, counter

I am working with an API such that on clicking button "show more" there's some counter which increases itself by 25 and display next content:

```
constructor(props){
this.state = { counter: 0}}
showMore = () => {
axios.get(some_random_link/append/${this.state.counter + 25}/0
  }.then(res => {
  this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 25 });
});

render(){
return(
<div>

 <button onClick={this.showMore}>show more</button>

</div>
```

Expected:

```
some_random_link/append/25/0
some_random_link/append/50/0
some_random_link/append/75/0
```

Actual:

```
some_random_link/append/25/0
some_random_link/append/25/0
some_random_link/append/25/0
```

Comment: `axios` and `setState` both are `async`. Try to use `async`/`await`.

Comment: I was [not able to reproduce the error](https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer57853045-w4pvi) (but make sure to add `super(props)` as the first call in the constructor. Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: Did the Axios request succeed? The code won't increment the counter if the request fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is an async process, hence when you want to update a state by using the previous one then do it this way

```js
class Counter {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
  }

  _showMore = () => {
    const { counter } = this.state;
    axios.get(`some_random_link/append/${counter + 25}/0`).then(res => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 25 }));
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this._showMore}>show more</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call axios call after setState()

```js
class Counter {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
  }

  showMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      ({ counter }) => ({ counter: counter + 25 }),
      () => {
        axios.get(`some_random_link/${this.state.counter}/0`); // this.state.counter already updated
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.showMore}>show more</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState()` is asynchronous! so instead of `this.setState({})`
change it to

```
this.setState(prev => counter : prev.counter + 25)
```

For more details check this link:
[Beware: React setState is asynchronous!](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={counter:0};
}
  showMore = () => {
    axios
      .get(`/fake/fake/fake/${this.state.counter}`)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("fake data");
      })
      .catch(() => {
      console.log(this.state.counter)
        
        this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 25 }));
      });
  };
  
  render(){
    return (
       <span style={{background:"green",color:"#fff",padding:"15px",cursor:"pointer"}}onClick={this.showMore}>PLZ CLICK ME</span>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```